# specify default goal for all plugin executions

Tags: maven, default, maven-plugin, execution

I'm going to have multiple executions of my custom maven plugin written into my project's pom.xml. My config went like this:

```
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>pluginId</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>ex-1</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>goal-name</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <option>value_1</option>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>ex-2</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>goal-name</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <option>value_2</option>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <!-- quite plenty more executions here -->
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <commonOption>common_value</commonOption>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
...
```

... all along with maven specs, just like in the examples and it works ok.

But there is quiet a lot of redundancy - every execution (about 20 of them) have own section of goals, and all of them have the exact same one goal specified. Thought to myself - I'd specify one default in plugin section. Looked into maven pom xml-schema and - hooray, there is an option for that. I've gone up to the following:

```
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>pluginId</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>ex-1</id>
          <configuration>
            <option>value_1</option>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>ex-2</id>
          <configuration>
            <option>value_2</option>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <!-- same plenty more executions changed likewise -->
      </executions>
      <goals>
        <goal>goal-name</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <commonOption>common_value</commonOption>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
...
```

... and bam! it doesn't work. Pom is being parsed, project is built, but plugin is not executed - not even once. Why? Am I mistaken, or something? Lack of feature in maven? Bug?

Comment: To which life cycle phase is your plugin bound?

Comment: It's bound to initialize phase. And I'm testing it by invoking `mvn initialize` or `mvn install`. None works.

Comment: Have you tried `mvn -X install` and take a deeper look into the log file?

Comment: Just tried it. Nothing there. When I've wrote goal into one execution - it have ran. When I didn't - nothing related to my plugin appeared in the log.

Comment: Using a `<goals></goals>` section in the plugin element doesn't work on build : `Plugin contains a <goals/> section: this is IGNORED - please use <executions/> instead.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Maven Model documentation](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-model/maven.html#class_plugin) the `goals` element in `plugin` is deprecated and unused by Maven.

Comment: Aw, you're right. It not only deprecated, but also broken. That's why. Thanks for pointing that out.